# Spring 2.5 Form Validation Errors found in Validator Implementation don't update View <form:error/> tags

Tags: java, forms, spring, validation, spring-mvc

For reference, I have been largely using this:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/

Basically, I have a class called EJournalValidator.java:

```
package com.blah.blah.validator;

import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import com.blah.blah.EJournalForm;

public class EJournalValidator implements Validator{

    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return EJournalForm.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "strStartDate",
                "ejournal.strStartDate", "Field name is required.");
    }

}
```

It is mapped to the controller in my servlet.xml which contains some important aspects in my spring 2.5 beans list:

```
<bean name="/app/eJournal.html" class="com.blah.blah.EJournalController">
    <property name="formView" value="/app/eJournal"/>
    <property name="validator">
        <bean class="com.blah.blah.EJournalValidator" />
    </property> 
</bean>
<bean name="/app/eJournalResult.html" class="com.blah.blah.EJournalResultController"></bean>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
      <list>
        <value>/WEB-INF/messages/message</value>
      </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver"/>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

It validates the search criteria in my form, represented by our model .java file and a controller for form load and submission (for us showForm() and handleRequest()). The trouble is, my view doesn't seem to get updated where my  tag is in my .jsp:

```
<td><form:input id="strStartDate" path="strStartDate"/></td>
<td><form:errors path="strStartDate" cssClass="error" /></td>
```

Unfortunately, even though I *know* an error is flagged appropriately when I submit null for this field via a break point in my EJournalValidator.java file, the error isn't updated in the view. Any idea why that might be? Some say if you redirect using something like:

```
return "redirect:/spring/person/list";
```

Then that can cause something like this, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

In debugging, these were errors found if I put a breakpoint in my validate method of EJournalValidator.java and inspected the errors variable when I try to submit blank in the field I'm checking:

> org.springframework.validation.BindException:
>   org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>   Field error in object 'ej' on field 'strStartDate': rejected value [];
>   codes
>   [ejournal.strStartDate.ej.strStartDate,ejournal.strStartDate.strStartDate,ejournal.strStartDate.java.lang.String,ejournal.strStartDate];
>   arguments []; default message [Field name is required.]

Any ideas why the errors found when debugging don't appear to the user?

**Edit**: Adding Controller handleRequest method in case it is needed to be known.

```
protected ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
        throws Exception {
    EJournalForm form = (EJournalForm) command;
    form.setUser(getUser());

    form.load(request, false);

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    session.setAttribute(LBIBOConstants.SESSION_VAR_TAB_ALERT_MSG, null);

    return new ModelAndView(getFormView(), getCommandName(), form);
}
```

**Edit 2**: Adding snippet from SimpleFormController which seems to be what it is stuck on. It never hits my Controller's handleRequest() method unless no errors existed when it checks this:

```
protected ModelAndView processFormSubmission(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
        throws Exception {

    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Data binding errors: " + errors.getErrorCount());
        }
        return showForm(request, response, errors);
    }
    else if (isFormChangeRequest(request, command)) {
        logger.debug("Detected form change request -> routing request to onFormChange");
        onFormChange(request, response, command, errors);
        return showForm(request, response, errors);
    }
    else {
        logger.debug("No errors -> processing submit");
        return onSubmit(request, response, command, errors);
    }
}
```

Something further I noticed... because of this I was going to override my Controller methods but realized I am extending SessionSimpleFormController and not SimpleFormController. Looking into this now as to why one would extend one or the other since I based this on someone else's work first, then noticed in the link I shown above they were using SimpleFormController.

Comment: Did you define properties file(which contains ejournal.strStartDate) in configuration?

Comment: I think so, in my message.properties file that I use for internationalization that I know works for the rest of the view, I have this entry:

ejournal.strStartDate=Invalid entry for date

Comment: I should name that differently as a message such as ejournal.strStartDateError or something indicating that's the error message, but yeah, seems fine on that front.

Comment: Plus, if it couldn't find that, the message would then use the default "Field name is required." I specified, yes?

Comment: I am starting to look at something important one user had mentioned, but not sure if it will shape up to be my problem yet:

"I finally got my form validation to work. As it turned out, Spring was adding the BindingResult object to the model, but under a different name (the classname beginning with lower case) than the command name I am using in my form tag. Changing the command name to reflect the name Spring is using to add the BindingResult to the model, got my form validation to work as expected"

Comment: In the handleRequest method in controller, why are you using getFormView() and getCommandName()? You can directly pass the view name you want it to on error and command name you specified in that view.

Comment: I can certainly do that too, I have seen a great deal of people do it that way, and the only reason I did that is because other spring pages developed by individuals no longer here did that to get their view and command names.

Comment: Yeah, I changed that bit to 

return new ModelAndView("app/eJournal", "ej", form);

and it doesn't seem to be much different. The form behaves like it did previously (form submission still works, but we still aren't getting the validation errors to appear where that tag is placed :(

Comment: You are breaking proper error message due to not passing along the actual binding errors. You should do something like `return new ModelAndView(getFormView(), errors.getModel())` as that will preserve the errors. You are constructing a whole new (and empty) model leaving out the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your handleRequest method to return existing form/model object if error occurred during validation. When you return new ModelAndView, its clearing the errors and as such you don't see them in view. Try with RedirectView to redirect to same view without loss of errors bound to your form/model as:

```
    protected ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
            throws Exception {
        EJournalForm form = (EJournalForm) command;
        form.setUser(getUser());
        form.load(request, false);

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        session.setAttribute(LBIBOConstants.SESSION_VAR_TAB_ALERT_MSG, null);

        if(errors.hasErrors()){
            return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(getFormView()));
        }else{
            return new ModelAndView("anotherView", "commandName", form);
        }   
    }
```

From Spring 3+, getFormView() and getCommandName() are deprecated.

Comment: That didn't seem to work, sadly, as when I debug it never gets to this point to check for errors. This is because as I step through things, it lands in the SimpleFormController, where it does something different based on if there were errors or not (see my Edit above for more info).

Comment: @Prasad the whole `SimpleFormController` is deprecated as of Spring 3.x and removed in Spring 4.

Comment: @M. Deinum that's correct, but if you see aohm1989 is using spring 2.5 version.

Answer (score 0):

I did fix this, in the end I had started to use the SimpleFormController as opposed to SessionSimpleFormController, and changed around a few things.

In the end, it looked something like this... but maybe there was a way to still get this to work with the Session controller.

```
public class EJournalController extends SimpleFormController {

public EJournalController() {
    setCommandClass(EJournalForm.class);
    setCommandName("ej"); 
}

@Override
protected ModelAndView showForm (HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, BindException errors) throws Exception {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calMidnight= Calendar.getInstance();
    calMidnight.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calMidnight.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calMidnight.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

    ModelAndView view = null;

    LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request);
    localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, LocaleUtilities.getUsersLocale(session));

    EJournalForm form = new EJournalForm();
    view = new ModelAndView(getFormView(), getCommandName(), form);
    form.setStrStartDate(form.getSdfDate().format(cal.getTime()).toString());
    form.setStrEndDate(form.getSdfDate().format(cal.getTime()).toString());
    form.setStrStartTime(form.getSdfTime().format(calMidnight.getTime()).toString());
    form.setStrEndTime(form.getSdfTime().format(cal.getTime()).toString());

    return view;
}

protected ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
        throws Exception {

    EJournalForm form = (EJournalForm) command;

    if(errors.hasErrors()){
        return onSubmit(request, response, command, errors);
    }
    else{
        form.load(request, false);          
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        session.setAttribute(LBIBOConstants.SESSION_VAR_TAB_ALERT_MSG, null);
        return new ModelAndView("app/eJournal", "ej", form);
    }  
}

@Override
protected ModelAndView processFormSubmission(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception {
        return handleRequest(request, response, command, errors);
}
```

}

Comment: This basically breaks the whole flow that is in the `SimpleFormController`. In general you should only need to implement the `onSubmit` method, whereas you have a `handleRequest` which isn't part of the normal flow.

Comment: Will do, thanks for clarifying as it was just what I could get to work and I was fairly confident there could be improvements.